# Incorrect dependency in class & \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository already exists error in context object How to solve it?

Tags: extensions, magento2.1.6

```
<?php

namespace Identixweb\Requestquote\Block\Requestquote;
use Identixweb\Requestquote\Block\BaseBlock; 
class Quote extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_quoteCollectionFactory;
    protected $_assetRepo;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Identixweb\Requestquote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\CollectionFactory $quoteCollectionFactory, 
        \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,       
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_quoteCollectionFactory = $quoteCollectionFactory; 
        $this->_assetRepo = $assetRepo; 
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getRequestCollection(){
       $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
       $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');  
      if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $customerId = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
        $collection = $this->_quoteCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addFieldToSelect('*');
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('user_id',$customerId);
        $collection->setOrder('id', 'DESC');
        return $collection;
     }
   }

}
```

Comment: Remove \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo and get Repository using $context->getAssetRepository();

Comment: @ Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd.  Thanks for your answer it is solve my problem. i'll  appriciate this....!!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `\Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,` from __construct argument and inside __construct replace `$this->_assetRepo = $assetRepo;` with `$this->_assetRepo = $context->getAssetRepository();`